# Syntax error in removing bad character in groovy

Tags: groovy, groovyshell, groovy-console

Hello I have a string like `a= " $ 2 187.00"` . I tried removing all the white spaces and the bad characters like `a.replaceAll("\\s","").replace("$","")` . but i am getting error
`Impossible to parse JSON response: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: bad escaped character` how to remove the bad character in this expression so that the value becomes 2187.00.Kindly help me .Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def a = ' $ 2 187.00'
a.replaceAll(/\s/,"").replaceAll(/\$/,"")

// or simply
a.replaceAll(/[\s\$]/,"")
```

It should return `2187.00`.

Note

1. that `$` has special meaning in double quoted strings literals `""` , called as `GString`.
2. In groovy, you can user regex literal, using that is better than using regex with multiple escape sequences in string.

Comment: Thanks kunal it worked how to convert the result to numeric please help me i am stuck.Thank you

Comment: Just add `as Double` to end of expression, the string will be converted to Double (or float if you want)

Comment: Hey kunal i tried but i am getting following error groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: asDouble for class: java.lang.String
 at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:2) i tried 
a.replaceAll(/\s/,"").replaceAll(/\$/,"").asDouble please help me